# How many different endings are there?

Tags: far-cry-4

So I know of the alternate ending you get in 15 minutes of the game starting, I know you can get the ending where you kill Pagan Min, but are there different endings depending on who I sided with and the actions I made in game?

So for my first run I sided with Amita but I made the decision not to kill Sabal; would the ending change if I had killed Sabal? How many endings are there in game, and does anything I do in game affect that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are 4 endings:

- After dining with Pagan in the very beginning, wait for him to return back to the table (around 15 min), and this will trigger the 1st ending
- At the end of the game, you can choose to kill Pagan, this will trigger the 2nd ending
- At the end of the game, you can choose not to kill Pagan, and go with Pagan to scatter your mother's ashes. Pagan will fly away on his helicopter, and you do not shoot the helicopter down.
- At the end of the game, you can choose not to kill Pagan, and go with Pagan to scatter your mother's ashes. Pagan will fly away on his helicopter, and if you have an RPG or Grenade Launcher with you you can take out his helicopter, which creates a mini area, where you can loot his body (amongst the helicopter wreckage)

There are [2 secret endings](http://www.gamefront.com/far-cry-4-post-credit-sabal-amita-scene-locations/), that happen no matter what and vary depending on the ally you sided with (Amita/Sabal):

Sabal

- Travel to **Jalendu Temple**, the same temple you were tasked with destroying or saving in a previous Golden Path mission, to find Sabal’s scene.
- Here you’ll witness Sabal putting subjects to death for turning against Kyrat’s national religion. This cutscene only appears if you side with Sabal and make him leader of the Golden Path.

Amita

- Travel to the town of **Tirtha** to see how Amita gets labor. This scene can only be found if you make Amita the leader of the Golden Path by destroying Jalendu Temple.
- Golden Path soldiers are rounding up children for slave labor in her opium farms.

Comment: Yes, but even if you side with one of them, you can choose to kill or spare the other one; does that choice make any difference to the ending at all ? From your description here, it seems like the answer to that is "no" ?

Comment: @Agrajag There is no difference to either of the endings, if you choose to kill/spare Amita/Sabal. The only difference is the "secret" endings, the ones that trigger at specfic locations depending on which faction you sided with.

Answer (score 1):

It does matter. After the epilogue and talking for the last time with the drug dudes there is a hidden video for Sabal or Amita.

You find Sabal on the temple island killing the followers of pagan. I'm still searching for Amitas end sequence; I want to know if she's crazy like Sabal.

Throughout the game I always found Sabal had the better reasons but after all Sabal is just a power hungry lunatic. I'm so curious if Amita is one too.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't matter if you kill Amita/Sabal but when you get to Pagan, dont shot him and you will get another ending.This is the onley other ending. so with the hidden one that's 3 possible endings

Comment: You can actually edit your previous answer if you'd prefer. I'd recommend simply deleting it instead at this point.

Answer (score -2):

Amita's ending is she goes into everyone's house and takes the men and children and forces them to join the golden army. She also sends bhadra "away" so the golden path don't rally behind her